# how to select the nth-child of dynamically generated row

Tags: jquery

onfocusout() accessing the quantity and price from the dynamically generated row, multiply them and assign it to the total.

My Form:

```
       <table id="dynamic-field" class="table table-striped table-bordered  
       dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <!-- <th> S.No </th> -->
              <th> Product Name </th>
              <th> Quantity </th>
              <th> Price </th>
              <th> Total </th>
              <th style="text-align: center;"> <i class="fa fa-plus btn 
              btn-success" id="addProduct"></i></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td style="width: 30%">
            <select id="product_id" name="product_id[]" 
            class="formcontrol" 
            required="">
            <option> --- Select ---</option>
            @foreach($products as $product)
            <option value="{{ $product->id }}"> {{ $product->name }} 
            </option>
            @endforeach
            </select>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 20%">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="quantity" 
            ame="quantity[]" required="">
            </td>
            <td style="width: 20%">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="price" 
            name="price[]" required="">
            </td>
            <td style="width: 20%">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="total" 
            name="total[]" required="" >
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">
            <i class="fa fa-remove btn btn-danger"></i>
            </td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="sales_information">

          </tbody><!-- TBODY End -->
        </table><!-- TABLE End -->
```

I have tried the following code but this did not work for me:

```
$(document).on('focusout', '#dynamic-field tr', function(e) 
  {
    var price = $(this).find('td:nth-child(1)').val();
    alert(price);
    var quantity = $(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').val();
    var result = price * quantity;
    $('#total').val(result);
  });
```

It shows me blank on alert.

Comment: Child of a `<tr>` would be a `<th>` or `<td>` not a form control. Only form controls have value. If looking for text ..use `text()` , if looking for input value need to go deeper than child. Show the relevant html

Comment: `:nth-child()` is not zero-based. Maybe it's your issue... Maybe it's something else.

Comment: I have uploaded the html. Please check it now #charlietfl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't repeat ID's in a page so change the id's on the form controls to classes and then simply target those classes.

```
<input type="number" class="form-control quantity" name="quantity[]" required="">
```

Also you are trying to target wrong `nth-child()` since `nth-child is not zero based like indexing is

```
$(document).on('focusout', '#dynamic-field tr :input', function(e) 
  {
    var price = $(this).find('.price').val();
    alert(price);
    var quantity = $(this).find('.quantity').val();
    var result = price * quantity;
    $(this).find('.total').val(result);
  });
```

Comment: I removed the id's and added class to all input fields and updated my code as you suggested but still it gives "undefined" :(

Comment: Removing the :input from 'selector' did the trick. It is working fine now. Thanks